# How to find out the deep linking path to all apps?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

```
Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?phone=${phoneNumber}`)
```

Take one example, the above is the code to navigate user from our app directly to contact window on WhatsApp.

And now I'm wondering how to navigate user to my company page on facebook page?

```
Linking.canOpenURL('fb://profile/mycompanypage')
```

The above not working of course. And other than that, usually how do we know what is the url for us to navigate to the apps?
For example particular Youtube Channel or Vimeo Channel or Twitter profile?

Comment: Why you are not using URL directly ?

Comment: If we are using the URL directly, it will navigate user to browser by default right? Instead I wish to navigate them to mobile app instead

Comment: are you trying in android or ios?

Comment: @HeisenBrg: I'm targetting both. But since Android is working from the answer below, I might only lack of iOS solution for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Facebook you can use these scheme

- for Android `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=${url}` (`url` is the fb classical url you use in browser)
- for IOS <s>`fb://page/PAGEID`</s> `fb://profile/PAGEID` you can find the `PAGEID` of your company page here https://findmyfbid.com/

The IOS solution is great when you don't have to generate the url on the fly which works for you i think. In a different case you'll have to use the FB SDK.

As for your other question: i generally go to the ressources website of the said app to find the right scheme for linking. But maybe there is a place where all those informations can be found ...

EDIT: IOS scheme was wrong

Comment: iOS solution is not working, it will only navigate user to fb app but not directly to the my page. Wondering if you can point me to the specific API provided by fbsdk? because I don't see any relevant API provided by fbsdk for opening specific page

Comment: As for Android, I've just tested and it's working fantastically, just that it required a little time to load the facebook app.

Comment: I've found the solution for iOS. The correct url should be `fb://profile/PAGEID`. You've done me a great help. Thanks a lot!!